# How to return hibernate collection entities without returning root entity

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I would like to get elements of a collection (Set<SheetConfig>) for a set of objects (WorkbookConfig) from Hibernate without getting the primary objects(WorkbookConfig).

The underlying tables look like this:

> workbook_config -> workbook_config_sheet_join <- sheet_config

If I just run it in my SQL utility, a successful SQL statement looks like this:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT sheet_config_id FROM sheet_config AS sc 
    LEFT JOIN workbook_config_sheet_join AS wcsj 
       ON sc.sheet_config_id = wcsj.sheet_config_id
    LEFT JOIN workbook_config AS wc 
       ON wc.workbook_config_id = wcsj.workbook_config_id
WHERE wc.group_id ="1"
ORDER BY sheet_name;
```

I would like to do this properly without using HQL.

My UNSUCCESSFUL attempt has resulted in this:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<SheetConfig> findAllForUser() {

    List<SheetConfig> sheetConfigs = null;
    Session session = getSession();

    Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(WorkbookConfig.class)
            .add(Restrictions.in(GROUP, getGroupsForUser()))
            .setFetchMode(SHEET_CONFIGS, FetchMode.JOIN);

    sheetConfigs = (List<SheetConfig>) crit.list();

    return sheetConfigs;
}
```

This is still giving me WorkbookConfigs, but what I would like to do in a single pass is get SheetConfigs.  I have spent the day on the Internet trying to find a coherent explanation of the Hibernate API, and I haven't been able to find what I would think is a solution to a fairly common requirement.  I can always back out and just do most of the work in Java, but it seems like I should be able to do this with the Hibernate API.  I appreciate any help, and also, if you can recommend a reference that explains not simply querying collections, but returning them, I would be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

Did you look into the setProjection method on Criteria?
Using the `setProjection` method lets you select properties or objects from the executed query.

[Hibernate Criteria documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html)

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not correct.  The setProjection method only works on simple parameters, not on Sets.

Comment: Did you try something like Projections.projectionList() and add this list as your Criteria projection?

Comment: Projections do not work on Collections.--See the note in this reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18060880/getting-collections-using-projectionhibernate